# design tables with multi prerequisites

Tags: database-design, schema, psql

I am working on a browser game and currently on the data modelling part. This is a browser game where every player has one or multiple village, with different buildings, and each building can be upgraded to level 20.

However, to build or upgrade a building, it is possible to have one of more prerequisites. Example: to build building C you must already have building B level 5 and building A level 9. Note that prerequisites are always building levels.

So there will be always 3 options when a player want to upgrade / build a building:

- no prerequisites
- 1 prerequisites
- 2 or more prerequisites

In my PSQL database, I have 2 different schemas, one for transactions tables and one for master tables.

What I has thinking to do is to create 2 different tables:

**1) master.building_upgrades**
This table store the cost of upgrade / build a building (ressources and prerequisites). Example: To upgrade your building Y to level 10 You must have 100 wood, 50 iron and building A level 7.

```
CREATE TABLE
  master.buildings_upgrades (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    building_id integer NOT NULL, \* the id of the building we want to build or upgrade *\
    level INT2, \* level of the building, from 0 to 20, the cost is usually higher when level is higher*\
    wood integer NOT NULL, \* wood cost*\
    clay integer NOT NULL, \* clay cost*\
    iron integer NOT NULL, \* iron cost*\
    corn integer NOT NULL, \* corn cost*\
    requirements_id integer NOT NULL, \* the column in question that I added to store prerequisites, set to NULL if no pre-requisites*\
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (building_id) REFERENCES transactions.buildings(id),    
    FOREIGN KEY (requirements_id) REFERENCES master.buildings_requirements(id) 
  );
```

In this table, I added a requirements_id column. What I am thinking to do is:

1. This column will be set to 'null' if there is no prerequisites
2. If there is one or more prerequisites, the value of this column will always be present in a column present in `master.building_requirements`:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE
     master.buildings_requirements (
       id serial NOT NULL,
       building_id integer NOT NULL, \* what building must be present in order to built it *\
       level integer NOT NULL, \* and which level is required*\
       PRIMARY KEY (id),
       FOREIGN KEY (building_id) REFERENCES master.buildings(id)
   );
   ```

My issue is, what to do if there are multiple requirements? I won't be able to have a primary key then. Should I denormalize the `buildings_requirements` table?

Comment: Looks like you need a many:many join table `upgrade_requirement (upgrade_id, requirement_id)`